# retrain object_detection not trained

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Background:

- Windows 10
- Tensorflow: 1.12

Followed the official document [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html). As the dataset is generated from experiment, so there are not many images available, about 50 training image and 10 test image. The pre-trained model is **ssd_inception_v2_coco**. When training using

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config
```

saw the following output and the program quit.

```
(a million lines here...)
W0423 15:59:38.764785 21492 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/BatchNorm/beta/RMSProp] is not available in checkpoint
W0423 15:59:38.765782 21492 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/BatchNorm/beta/RMSProp_1] is not available in checkpoint
W0423 15:59:38.765782 21492 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/BatchNorm/gamma/ExponentialMovingAverage] is not available in checkpoint
W0423 15:59:38.765782 21492 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/BatchNorm/gamma/RMSProp] is not available in checkpoint
W0423 15:59:38.765782 21492 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/BatchNorm/gamma/RMSProp_1] is not available in checkpoint
W0423 15:59:38.765782 21492 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage] is not available in checkpoint
W0423 15:59:38.765782 21492 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/weights/RMSProp] is not available in checkpoint
W0423 15:59:38.765782 21492 variables_helper.py:144] Variable [FeatureExtractor/InceptionV2/Mixed_5c_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/weights/RMSProp_1] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:tensorflow:From d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\slim\python\slim\learning.py:737: Supervisor.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.supervisor) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession
W0423 15:59:39.539828 21492 tf_logging.py:125] From d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\slim\python\slim\learning.py:737: Supervisor.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.supervisor) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession
2019-04-23 15:59:41.155297: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2019-04-23 15:59:41.385078: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7085
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 11.00GiB freeMemory: 9.11GiB
2019-04-23 15:59:41.390824: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-04-23 15:59:42.311427: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-04-23 15:59:42.322811: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0
2019-04-23 15:59:42.324856: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N
2019-04-23 15:59:42.327029: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 8799 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from pre-trained-model/model.ckpt
I0423 15:59:46.439763 21492 tf_logging.py:115] Restoring parameters from pre-trained-model/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
I0423 15:59:46.674186 21492 tf_logging.py:115] Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
I0423 15:59:47.319484 21492 tf_logging.py:115] Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
I0423 15:59:54.453117 21492 tf_logging.py:115] Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt
I0423 15:59:54.647598 15672 tf_logging.py:115] Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
I0423 15:59:54.651614 21492 tf_logging.py:115] Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
I0423 16:00:01.125150  4792 tf_logging.py:159] global_step/sec: 0

D:\workspace\demo>
```

And here is the configure file:

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
        reduce_boxes_in_lowest_layer: true
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 3
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_inception_v2'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 0
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 4
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0004
          decay_steps: 5000
          decay_factor: 0.99
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "pre-trained-model/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 5
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 5
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

I guess the model is not get trained because the tensorboard looks like this:

[image]

Well, any idea how to make the training start?

Comment: Can you give your cmd line to start train?

Comment: @yann It's `python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config`.

Comment: @danyfang Thanks for replay. I moved the `config` file outside of `training` folder and delete everything there. Moreover, also deleted the folder in `pre-trained-model` that comes along with the `ssd_inception_v2_coco.zip` file that was mentioned in your commends.

Comment: @danyfang actually nothing changed this time.

Comment: I followed the exact same tutorial and I used specifically the config file you pasted here with some paths changed and the training started normally on my machine. (Linux + CPU). Previously I did not follow the tutorial and my comment was wrong. I think the config file is OK but the problem might be something else. You can investigate part by part, for example, make sure the tfrecord file is OK, and make sure the tensorflow GPU worked fine, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `--num_train_steps=10` to your cmd.

Comment: Tried, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after resize the images to 600 * 300, things works.